# Radeon 6950 not detected by "additional drivers" on 16.04

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, radeon

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer, I'm not happy but OK. The think which bugs me the most is that my Graphic-Card is not detected by the "Additional driver" thingy, like so:[image]

However if I use:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

I get the following result:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950] [1002:6719]
```

Which states that he does recognize it. What am I missing?
I have tried to reinstall the mesa-glx und stuff in that direction, but I'm really a beginner. Is the graphic card broken?

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that had been stated even before 16.04 was released was that it would not support the `fglrx` driver for ATI/AMD adapters.  If you want to keep using 16.04 you have to use the open source drivers.

Comment: Yes I know that, but should I not be able to select the open source drivers in the "additional driver" list? I cant use any driver at all

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04  And that would be indeed: No. "additional drivers" means 3rd party. That list is empty because AMD does not provide any drivers. And if the drivers provided by Ubuntu (that are installed by default) do not work properly ... file a bug report. Best option though would be to install 14.04 (yes, we know ;-))

Comment: The open source drivers are used by default.  They do not appear in **Additional drivers** if they are the only option.

Comment: So actually, the graphic card should be working out of the box? How can I recognize that this is the case? Because right now I cant even watch youtube videos on FULL HD without major lagging. The statement in thw additional drivers thingy is: The device is not working.. surely there is somthing off

Comment: In a terminal, type `lspci -k`.  Search for the VGA controller section and take a look at the two lines at the bottom.  They will show you the kernel modules and drivers used.  The **Device is not working** refers to the CPU, not the graphics adapter.  It's not a correct statement actually.  It just means that the intel-microcode driver is not installed.

Comment: Ah Ok that was very helpful actually. Thank you!